# Regex match a line if a specific string occurs more than once in a line

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio-2015

I know how to search for two different specific strings in one line, but not how to check if a single specific string occurs more than once in a line. Can this be done? Whether it matches the whole line or if it matches the strings themselves is not important to me.

Example:

I would like to  specify **'Spani'** and have it match

> The Spaniard speaks Spanish

but ***not:***

> The Spaniard speaks German

Can something like this be done with Regex that I am unaware of? If not, is there a way to check the inverse, which is basically the same thing:

Does a specific string only occur once in a line?

Comment: `^.*(Spani.*){2}$` with multi-line option turned on

Comment: how about to return any substring with length n which occured more than one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a regex similar to that noted in @Steven Doggart's comment above so that you end up with: `^.*(Spani.*){2}$`

You should use [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure you don't search for any regex reserved characters.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public bool HasMatches(string input, string search, int times)
{
    var pattern = $"^.*({Regex.Escape(search)}.*){{{times}}}";
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
}
```

And run it like this:

```
var input = "The Spaniard speaks Spanish";
HasMatches(input, "Spani", 2);

input = "The Spaniard speaks German";
HasMatches(input, "Spani", 2);

input = "The Spaniard speaks Spanish" + Environment.NewLine + "The Spaniard speaks German";
HasMatches(input, "Spani", 2);
```

Comment: `Regex.Escape` - nice! Do you really need the `^.*` at the beginning?

Comment: No, probably not actually. It was just a literal translation of the "in one line" requirement into regex.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like that would be pretty simple:

```
Spani.+Spani
```

Assuming you have "Spani" in a variable

```
var toMatch = "Spani";

var pattern = $"{toMatch}.+{toMatch}";
```

(Don't include Regex special characters in `toMatch`.)